# PHP isn't getting array value in other function if it's not declared in function scope

Tags: php

I'm trying get a value of my array, but return error message:

```
Undefined variable: titulo_por_permissao in /home/user/scripts/code.php on line 10
```

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $titulo_por_permissao = [
        0 => 'Membro',
        1 => 'Ponto de venda',
        2 => 'Representante',
        5 => 'Administrador'
    ];
    
function pegaTitulo($permissao){
    $result = $titulo_por_permissao[$permissao] ? $titulo_por_permissao[$permissao] : 'Nenhum';
    return $result; 
}
echo pegaTitulo(1);
```

If i put it this way, it works:

```
<?php
    $titulo_por_permissao = [
        0 => 'Membro',
        1 => 'Ponto de venda',
        2 => 'Representante',
        5 => 'Administrador'
    ];
    
function pegaTitulo($permissao,$titulo_por_permissao){
    $result = $titulo_por_permissao[$permissao] ? $titulo_por_permissao[$permissao] : 'Nenhum';
    return $result; 
}
echo pegaTitulo(1,$titulo_por_permissao);
```

What i wnat is declare my var out of function scope and use it in the function without send as an attribute.

Comment: `What i wnat is declare my var out of function scope and use it in the function without send as an attribute.`...why? That's the sort of hideous thing JavaScript lets you do, and it usually causes more problems than it solves. Scope exists for many good reasons, and global variables are usually a maintenance nightmare. But if you _really_ want to, then read https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php and note the bit about the `global` keyword.

Comment: Ty so much, i'll read here now <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it this way. But it is never recommended.

```
<?php
$titulo_por_permissao = [
        0 => 'Membro',
        1 => 'Ponto de venda',
        2 => 'Representante',
        5 => 'Administrador'
    ];
    
function pegaTitulo($permissao){
    global $titulo_por_permissao; //declare it as global variable
    $result = $titulo_por_permissao[$permissao] ? $titulo_por_permissao[$permissao] : 'Nenhum';
    return $result; 
}
echo pegaTitulo(2);
?>
```

Comment: Have any other way?

Comment: Nope. The only thing is passing into the function. Thats it.